# HTML/CSS Help making link-hover fill the whole navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web

Im trying to make the navigation bar highlight fully when we hover over a link but it's currently only working horizontally. I think its something really small I'm doing wrong and have been trying four hours. Heres the code I have:

```css
    html, body { 
    
    /*require html and body 100% height and width to allow other child elements to use percentages*/
    
     height: 100%; 
     width: 100%; 
     margin: 0;
    
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     color: black;
    }
    
    li {
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    
    div{
     margin-left: 2.5%;
     margin-right: 2.5%;
     margin-top: 1%;
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .content_section{
     height: 150%;
     margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
    
    #footer{
     height: 25%;
     margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
    
    #banner{
     margin-top: 2.5%;
     height: 15%;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    #banner img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    #navbar{
     padding: 0;
     height: 5%;
     

    text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #FFCB3D;
    }

    #navbar li a {
     display: block;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    
    #navbar ul a:hover{
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #FFF17C;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Sample Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="banner">
   <img src="resources/images/banner-image.png">  
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
   <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Page A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page E</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content_section">
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make the `ul` a `display: flex` parent to create a row out of the `li`'s, remove the `height` on `#navbar` so it's fluid based on the content, remove the `ul`'s default `margin`, then set `flex-grow: 1` on the `li`'s (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short) so they'll stretch to fill the parent evenly, then apply vertical `padding` to the `li > a`'s and remove the `height` and `float`s.

```css
    html, body { 
    
    /*require html and body 100% height and width to allow other child elements to use percentages*/
    
     height: 100%; 
     width: 100%; 
     margin: 0;
    
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     color: black;
    }
    
    li {
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    
    div{
     margin-left: 2.5%;
     margin-right: 2.5%;
     margin-top: 1%;
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .content_section{
     height: 150%;
     margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
    
    #footer{
     height: 25%;
     margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
    
    #banner{
     margin-top: 2.5%;
     height: 15%;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    #banner img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    #navbar{
     padding: 0;          
     position: relative;
     background-color: #FFCB3D;
      text-align: center;
    }
    ul#navbar {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #navbar li { 
      flex: 1 0 0;
    }

    #navbar li a {
     display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 1em 0;
    }
    
    #navbar ul a:hover{
     background-color: #FFF17C;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Sample Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="banner">
   <img src="resources/images/banner-image.png">  
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
   <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Page A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page E</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content_section">
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```